# How to position 2 text components at the end of a view in RN?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-component

I want to achieve this result

[image]

But this is the current behaviour

[image]

As you can notice both `Text` components aren't aligned correctly.

This is the code

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 7, borderWidth: 2 }}>
     <Text style={{ color: '#0022FF', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 5 }}>2.6</Text>
     <Text style={{ color: '#0022FF', fontSize: 9, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>Bar</Text>
</View>
```

Can you guys help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work if you wrap both texts inside another `<Text>` component like so:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 7, borderWidth: 2 }}>
  <Text>
     <Text style={{ color: '#0022FF', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 5 }}>2.6</Text>
     <Text style={{ color: '#0022FF', fontSize: 9, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>Bar</Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: It works fine, but the space between the Text components is't working anymore (marginRight: 5 is ignored).Do you have any idea?

Comment: try to use `paddingRight` instead

Comment: I tried but nothing happened, I used some extra space for now like this {" "} or maybe I'm going to nest an other empty `View` between `Text` components. Thank you for the great answer